# How to delete a file from amazon S3 bucket using cURL

Tags: curl, amazon-s3, s3-bucket, amazon-s3-select, curl-commandline

I was trying to delete a file from s3 bucket which is hosted in my client's in-house storage `s3.fidapp.org`. I used below command but it didn't work. I'm getting below error.

```
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Secret Access Key and signing method.</Message>
```

Script to find signingKey

```
function hmac_sha256 {key="$1"    
data="$2"    
echo -n "$data" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "$key" -binary | base64| sed 
's/^.* //'}

secret="$1"    
date="$2"    
region="$3"    
service="$4"    
testaws4='AWS4'$secret

s1=$(echo -n $date | openssl sha256 -hmac AWS4$secret | sed 's/^.* //')    
s2=$(echo -n $region | openssl dgst -sha256 -mac HMAC -macopt hexkey:$s1 | 
   sed 's/^.* //')    
s3=$(echo -n $service | openssl dgst -sha256 -mac HMAC -macopt hexkey:$s2 | 
   sed 's/^.* //')    
signingkey=$(echo -n aws4_request | openssl dgst -sha256 -mac HMAC -macopt 
           hexkey:$s3 | sed 's/^.* //')
```

Delete Script

```
bucketName="test_bucket"    
accessKey="test-key"    
fileName="test.dat"    
Region="us-east-1"    
DateTime=`date -u +%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ`    
Date=`date -u +%Y%m%d`    
SecretKey="**********************"    
HashKey=e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855

CRequest="DELETE\n/test_bucket/\n\nhost:s3.fidapp.org\nx-amz-content- 
          sha256:"$HashKey"\n\nx-amz-date:"$DateTime"\n\nhost;x-amz-content- 
          sha256;x-amz-date\n"$HashKey"\n"    
CRHkey=`echo -en $CRequest|openssl dgst -sha256| cut -d ' ' -f2` 
StringToSign="AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n"$DateTime"\n"$Date"/us- 
      east-/s3/aws4_request\n"$CRHkey
SigningKey=`sh signing_key.sh $SecretKey $Date $Region s3`

echo -en $StringToSign | openssl dgst -sha256 -mac HMAC -macopt 
      hexkey:$SigningKey | sed 's/^.* //' |cut -d ' ' -f2 > Signature.txt    
cat Signature.txt

AuthorizationHeader="Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 
Credential="$accessKey"/"$Date"/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request, 
SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature="`cat 
Signature.txt`

curl -X DELETE https://s3.fidapp.org//${bucketName}/${fileName}    
-H "$AuthorizationHeader"    
-H "host: s3.fidapp.org"    
-H "X-Amz-Content-SHA256: "$HashKey    
-H "X-Amz-Date: "$DateTime
```

I used same command to upload a file to S3 bucket by replacing `DELETE` with `PUT`.

Please let me know if I'm missing anything or I have to change anything in the command.

Comment: Do you have permission to delete file on your bucket?

Comment: Please be sure to quote the error message *exactly*.  The `x-amz-content-sha256` would almost certainly need to be either the literal value `UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD` or the literal value `e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855` because a `DELETE` request has no payload and that value is the [sha256 of a zero-length string](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/26135/25027).

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - Thanks for the comment. I've tried both the ways and now edited my script and added error message. Still no luck. Could you suggest any other ways.

Comment: @dkb - Yes I have permission to delete.

Comment: This isn't a permissions error -- the signature is the problem.  How are you actually generating that signature?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - Added full script. Please take a look and let me know if anything missed

Comment: There may be any number of issues here, but the first one that I see is `CRequest="DELETE\n/test_bucket/\n`.  The literal string `/test_bucket/` does not belong here.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - that is the bucket name

Comment: @Shanti the *literal string* does not belong there, no matter what its meaning.  That is the place in the string to sign for the HTTP request path.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Can you please elaborate your answer.

Comment: It should be the same thing as the request path, something like `...DELETE\n/${bucketName}/${fileName}\n\nhost...` with variables, not a literal.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I've used the way which you mentioned and getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Error code SignatureDoesNotMatch generally comes when the signature we calculate and provide in our curl does not match with the corresponding matching signature prepared by S3 or Minio server based upon the headers we provide. Please make sure the headers provided in curl command match the content you have in your signature.

Also, in the URL which you have provided in your curl delete request, there seems to be an extra '/' after https://s3.fidapp.org/.